# vscode on Ubuntu is unable to open windows

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm having issues with vscode on Ubuntu running particular Python code (that seemingly relies on porting or connecting to an external application). The same code will run fine if I execute it directly from an Ubuntu terminal with the same env on the same machine.

Here's a couple of examples.

When I try to initiate `vedo.plotter.Plotter()` when running from vscode, I get this error:

```
ERROR: In /work/standalone-x64-build/VTK-source/Rendering/OpenGL2/vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow.cxx, line 1223
vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow (0x5587f7b42cf0): bad X server connection. DISPLAY=Aborted (core dumped)
```

If I run the same code directly in terminal, it runs fine, so this is an issue with the way vscode is configured, but I can't find any answers online. I've played with a few settings in vscode but with no success.

This seems to be an issue on all vscode installations I have running on Ubuntu (in this case 20.04). Here's the vscode info:

```
Version: 1.51.0
Commit: fcac248b077b55bae4ba5bab613fd6e9156c2f0c
Date: 2020-11-05T18:16:10.374Z
Electron: 9.3.3
Chrome: 83.0.4103.122
Node.js: 12.14.1
V8: 8.3.110.13-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.4.0-52-generic snap
```

Similarly, I'm unable to open up browser windows from vscode (for example plotly `fig.show()` and selenium `driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)` won't open browser windows. I get the following error with selenium:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
```

Again, this works fine direct from the terminal and everything works fine if run from a Windows or Mac installed vscode, so this is specific to this Ubuntu install.

I'd really appreciate any help!

Jonny